# Cannot use ModSecurity for SharePoint 2013

Tags: security, web-application

I'm trying to use ModSecurity for SharePoint sever.

I have a windows server 2012 with iis 8.5 and sharepoint 2013 installed.

I also installed modsecurity and configed follow `https://forums.iis.net/post/2103335.aspx`
with the file *web.config* in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80`
I had this error:

> The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'ModSecurity'
>   ...

[image: **The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'ModSecurity'**]

SharePoint server worked.

Modsecurity worked when I switch web server to iis default web.

[image: mod-security worked with iis 8.5]

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem a few hours ago.

The resolution is simply replacing `ModSecurity` by `modsecurity` in the files *applicationhost.config* and *web.config*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is not supported. So don't do it! Web.config files are managed automatically by Sharepoint, and there's not just one Web.config file.

As for your issue, which you should not fix given the above, you're most likely missing the configSection pieces...